# Android Firebase Phone Auth crashed when clicked button of empty edittext

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

With no problem, connected my app to firebase and I can test realtime database and other features, but when it comes to Phone Authentication, I am having problems. The problem is when `Edittext` is left empty and `Button` is clicked the app gets crashed. Don't know which code should be responsible for this problem.

Please help me to define it.

Comment: Show your code, what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have carefully read the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/PhoneAuthActivity.java#L204-L209) of phone auth in firebase you will have below code:

```
 private boolean validatePhoneNumber() {
    String phoneNumber = mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
```

Then either with `if-else` or `switch-case`

You should call this method
NOTE: `onCLick` method comes after `btn.setOnClickListener` depending upon your button id.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_start_verification:
            if (!validatePhoneNumber()) {
                return;
            }

            startPhoneNumberVerification(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.button_verify_phone:
            String code = mVerificationField.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
                mVerificationField.setError("Cannot be empty.");
                return;
            }

            verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, code);
            break;
        case R.id.button_resend:
            resendVerificationCode(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString(), mResendToken);
            break;
        case R.id.sign_out_button:
            signOut();
            break;
    }
}
```

Due to the codes which were not provided by you, I have written some references based on my own app. Please consider changing those and probably you wont get further crashes.